# I can encrypt but not decrypt with pycrypto in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, cryptography

I created this software in python3. The problem is that my software don't write the result if I want to decrypt a file.
I am using easygui for gui as a gui. Finally I don't have any error message. The software just close as usually but the file stay encrypted.

```
def decrypt(key, filename):
    chunksize = 64 * 1024
    outputFile = filename[11:]

    with open(filename, 'rb') as infile:
        filesize = int(infile.read(16))
        IV = infile.read(16)

        decryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV)

        with open(outputFile, 'wb') as outfile:
            while True:
                chunk = infile.read(chunksize)

                if len(chunk) == 0:
                    break

                outfile.write(decryptor.decrypt(chunk))
            outfile.truncate(filesize)


def getKey(password):
    hasher = SHA256.new(password.encode('utf-8'))
    return hasher.digest()


def Main():
    image = "./images/encryption.gif"
    msg = "Do you want to encrypt or decrypt a file ?"
    choices = ["Encrypt", "Decrypt", "Exit"]
    reply = buttonbox(msg, image=image, choices=choices)


    if reply == 'Encrypt':
         filename = fileopenbox(msg="Select the file to Encrypt",title="Select the file to Encrypt", default='*', filetypes=None, multiple=False)
        password = passwordbox(msg="Enter a password",title="Enter a password",default="")
        encrypt(getKey(password),filename)

     elif reply == 'Decrypt':
        filename = fileopenbox(msg="Select the file to Decrypt", title="Select the file to Decrypt", default='*', filetypes=None, multiple=False)
        password = passwordbox(msg="Enter a password",title="Enter a password",default="")
        decrypt(getKey(password),filename)

    else:
        sys.exit(0)


 if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Comment: Just reading an answer, and then posting an answer, consisting of a link to a GitHub site with your code and my answer integrated isn't normal behavior. If you want to post your code, provide the padding / unpadding and integrate it into my answer by editing it; you can then accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You have forgotten to take the requirements of [`AESCipher.encrypt` and `AESCipher.decrypt`](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.Cipher.blockalgo.BlockAlgo-class.html#encrypt) into consideration: you need to perform the required padding yourself:

> For MODE_ECB, MODE_CBC, and MODE_OFB, plaintext length (in bytes) must be a multiple of block_size.

Probably you will miss part of the ciphertext if you do not provide a message (file contents) that is exactly a multiple of 16 bytes as some part of the message stays in cache. So zero to 15 bytes may be stripped off of the input file each time you perform encryption.

Obviously for very small files up to 15 bytes nothing will be left.

Comment: There may be other issues of course. StackOverflow is not an online debugger, and we would be missing vital info to perform debugging anyway (input, output, encrypt method etc.)